# What's the advantage of 3-level laser over 4-level laser?

Tags: laser

Since it is way easier for a 4-level laser to get population inversion than 3-level laser, 3-level laser is still in use nowadays. So what's the advantage of 3-level laser over 4-level laser?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should take the view of an experimental physicist:

- Which atoms are available and where are their energy levels?
- How can I excite the atoms in order to get inversion?
- What are the properties which I need my laser to fulfill (e.g. line width, power, ...)?
- How complicated and stable is the set-up? How much does it cost and how long will it take to get the laser running?

Comment: +1 for first point. There are quite a few of the lanthanide ions (Er, Ho, Tm) working in three-level scheme. Of course 4-level would be better, but 3-level is what we have for these ions. And this is technology, so "good enough" is all we need.